# doubts in QT based chat app

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I have started making a desktop based very simple chat application designed with Qt and so far just made a front end of my chat application. This is going to be web based server and multiple clients application i.e. just like Google Talk and Yahoo Messenger chat application.

The real confusion is I am not sure of my approach so wanted some of your inputs on this. My chat GUI is designed in Qt and for client - server communication I am planning to use Boost Asio library.

I want to design a server which is hosted on web and make chat gui on my computer to send messages through it, but I don't know if I can do it with Boost Asio library.

I have taken a free hosting and domain name just for the sake of testing it as a server, however I am now completely clueless about how i should communicate with it using my chat GUI and configure server with BOOST.

This may sound too wide, but I just want approaches to how i should achieve my goal of communicating my QT based chat client to receive messages sent on web server. Also, is getting a free hosting and domain name enough to make it act as a web server?

PS:
I am using boost asio here because i am more interested in learning about its client - server communication.

I don't want to use QT's inbuilt chat client-server model because I want to make front end of chat in Qt, but for communication on back end I want to use c++/Boost Asio

Comment: I'd be surprised if "free hosting" (I assume web) will let you do anything more than upload some HTML or PHP files. Definitely not give you shell access and ability to run arbitrary binaries (as services), which you need if you want to use C++. You'll need at least a virtual machine, which won't be free. Considering you've don't even know how to start with the client/server part, I'd say worrying about a machine is premature -- you can easily develop everything you need locally, at most with a few virtuals to emulate the environment.

Comment: Similarly, GUI is an unnecessary distraction at this stage -- first solve the client/server part, and implement you client as a library that you can test independently (and automatically), and then embed in a GUI client. Split the problem up, the chat part on its own is enough for a book to address all the various issues. Take the time to decide what features you want, write down a detailed specification, and design the usage scenarios. It's not just about sending messages, you need to manage user accounts, handle authentication, contact lists, etc.....

Comment: @DanMašek I understand. As you said I only have option to upload HTML and PHP files in free hosting. Also, I already have started with client/server basics using Boost. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Well, you may want to take a look at how XMPP works, it (was) used for Facebook Messenger and Google Hangouts.

Comment: I just had a look and its nice to see they also have good library support. Would give it a try after reading little more in detail. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The back end can be written using Qt as well, boost::asio is a third-party library just as Qt is. Since Qt is an *application development* framework, not just a *gui* framework, you're free to leverage it for non-gui tasks as well - saves you from an extra library to mess with.